# printf for size_t

Tags: gcc, printf, string-formatting, size-t

Is there any way to give `printf` a `size_t` without either casting it first or generating a compiler warning? (I always compile with `-Wall`.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
printf("%zu", sizeof(whatever));
```

Comment: FWIW this only works for me with MinGW with `-std=c99`, and not `-std=gnu99`