# problems understanding the size_t type and the sizeof operator

Tags: c, arrays, printf, sizeof, size-t

```
void sizeof_test2();

void sizeof_test2()
{
    int array[5];
    size_t arr_size = sizeof(array);

    printf( "sizeof:\n"
            "array = %d\n"
            "arr_size = %d\n", sizeof(array), sizeof(arr_size));
}
```

GCC compiler output:

```
sizeof_test2.c: In function `sizeof_test2':  
sizeof_test2.c:6: error: `size_t' undeclared (first use in this function)  
sizeof_test2.c:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is<br>
reported only once sizeof_test2.c:6: error: for each function it<br>
appears in.) sizeof_test2.c:6: error: parse error before "arr_size"<br>
sizeof_test2.c:10: error: `arr_size' undeclared (first use in this<br>
function) make[2]:  [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/sizeof_test2.o]<br>
Error 1 make[1]:  [.build-conf] Error 2<br>
```

Don't know why I'm getting this error, what's the correct way of displaying a size_t type through `printf`?

Comment: `size_t` is defined in `stdlib.h` (I think), since you are getting an undeclared error.

Comment: added this: #include <stddef.h>
The problem got resolved.. should've thought of that, I did navigate to the header through NetBeans but didn't think of actually including it.. thanks.

Comment: That's the one. `stdlib.h` pulls it in I think, hence my mini confusion.

Comment: Also, you're using the wrong format code for `printf`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150056/printf-for-size-t

Comment: it's possible to use the `%d` format code (see page 271 of Deitel - C: How to Program, 6th ed.)

Comment: @user38541: I don't have that book to consult, but your paraphrasing of it is false. `%d` takes an `int`, so behavior is undefined, but the most likely thing that can go wrong is when `size_t` and `int` have different sizes. Then, you write two `size_t` varargs but `printf` will read two `int` varargs, and it will not print the correct values. If you're using a 32 bit C implementation, it might be that your code works, but this is an accident. If you want to use `%d`, cast the values to `int`: `(int)sizeof(array), (int)sizeof(arr_size)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` type is defined in `stddef.h` header (and other headers, for example `stdio.h`).

Note that in your program your are using `printf` function so you already have to include `stdio.h`.

Comment: Yes, I just included it.. thanks and sorry for my newbie mistake.

Answer (score 4):

stdlib is what you want, and for displaying it I think you're looking for the `%z` modifier

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t arr_size;
printf("%zu\n", arr_size);  // unsigned decimal 
printf("%zx\n", arr_size);  // hex
```

Comment: @user38541 - but keep in mind just %d or %u may not compile correctly on both 32 and 64 bit machines. The %z was added in for this in C99

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is not built-in type in C. You must include `<stddef.h>` or `<stdlib.h>` standard header where `size_t` is defined.